# SqLite - index ignored, query very slow on only 80k rows

Tags: sqlite, indexing

i am having difficulties in speeding up a sqlite query... there are a few other posts here with the same problem but none of those i found solved the problem for me.

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE  
(crateScore >= '0.0' AND  crateScore <= '1.0') AND 
(abs(crateScore - crateScoreSec) <= 1.0 OR 
(crateScoreSec IS NULL)) ORDER BY id DESC;
```

This query takes 1200 ms give or take, on a table with 80k rows. If i remove the order by clause it goes down to about 100ms.

i have run the Explain query plan and it outputs this:

```
4   0   0   SEARCH TABLE images USING INDEX idx_LogCrateScore (crateScore>? AND crateScore<?)
44  0   0   USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY
```

i have set up multiple indexes (more than needed) in different combinations to see what indexes it would use and if it would speed up on a given index, but the speed remains the same.

my indexes are:

```
CREATE INDEX "idx_Log" ON "images" ( "crateScore", "crateScoreSec" )
CREATE INDEX "idx_Log2" ON "images" ( "crateScore", "crateScoreSec", "id" )
CREATE INDEX "idx_LogCrateScore" ON "images" ( "crateScore" ASC )
CREATE INDEX "idx_LogCrateScoreSec" ON "images" ( "crateClassSec" ASC )
CREATE INDEX "idx_LogIdDesc" ON "images" ( "id" DESC )
```

so my questions are:

1. why is it creating a temp table for sorting and ignoring the id-index? can this be avoided?
2. is there anything else i can do to speed this query up even more?

any help is appreciated

Comment: Your EQP output suggests you're using a quite old version of sqlite. I'd start by upgrading to see if a newer version comes up with a better plan.